# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: column "----" of relation "-----" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, persistence, jpql

I'm getting this error while storing an object into database using persistence API. For me, it looks alright. Couldn't find the issue anywhere in the model class.

Please let me know if you need any other info.

Thanks in advance.

**Error:**

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Project] in context with path
>   [/Project] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: column
>   "first_name" of relation "users" does not exist   Position: 36; nested
>   exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: column
>   "first_name" of relation "users" does not exist   Position: 36] with
>   root cause org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column
>   "first_name" of relation "users" does not exist   Position: 36    at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
>   ......

**User.java**

```
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String password;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column( name = "phone" )
private String phone;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Address.class, mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Address> address;

private boolean enabled;

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "authorities",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id" ) )
@Column( name = "role" )
private Set<String> roles;

@Transient
private String password2;

public User()
{
    roles = new HashSet<String>();
    enabled=true;
}

public boolean isAdmin()
{
    return roles.contains( "ROLE_ADMIN" );
}

public boolean isUser()
{
    return roles.contains( "ROLE_USER" );
}

public Long getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId( Long id )
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail()
{
    return email;
}

public void setEmail( String email )
{
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword()
{
    return password;
}

public void setPassword( String password )
{
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName( String firstName )
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName( String lastName )
{
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getPhone()
{
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone( String phone )
{
    this.phone = phone;
}

public Set<String> getRoles()
{
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles( Set<String> roles )
{
    this.roles = roles;
}

public String getPassword2()
{
    return password2;
}

public void setPassword2( String password2 )
{
    this.password2 = password2;
}
```

}

**Database:**

```
create table users (
        id int8 not null,
        email varchar(255) not null unique,
        enabled boolean not null,
        first_name varchar(255),
        last_name varchar(255),
        password varchar(255) not null,
        phone varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    );
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/registration.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registrationPOST(@ModelAttribute User user, ModelMap models, SessionStatus sessionStatus)
    {
        user.setEnabled(false);
        user = userDao.saveUser(user);
        sessionStatus.setComplete();
        models.put("status","Check your email to confirm your account");
        return "user/registration";
    }
```

Comment: Some suggestion: doublecheck you are connecting to the right db, log your query and try it directly and see what's wrong with it

Comment: Sure. Thanks for suggestions.